# AngularJS - how to unit test directive that has no logic in it

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I want to do a very simple Jasmine test to test the following directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('kits.ui.components')

    .directive('toggle', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                onText: '@',
                offText: '@',
                ngModel: '=',
                label: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'modules/ui.components/toggle/views/toggle.view.html'
        };
    });
```

What is the best approach and recommendation for such simple directives?

Toggle View:

```
<div>
    <label data-auto="toggleLabel" for="toggle-input-{{$id}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        {{label}}
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 checkbox-inline">
        <label class="cnc-toggle">
            <input data-auto="toggleInput" ng-model="ngModel" id="toggle-input-{{$id}}" type="checkbox" class="toggleInput">
                <div class="track">
                    <div ng-show="ngModel" class="toggle-label on">
                        {{onText || 'ON'}}
                    </div>
                    <div ng-show="!ngModel" class="toggle-label off">
                        {{offText || 'OFF'}}
                    </div>
                <div class="handle"></div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please share toggle.view.html as well

Comment: Alright thanks. Ideally you should check that the directive is rendering the expected output. i.e. check if the directive has the label tag, check if the label name is correct etc.

Comment: Could you expand? A snippet of code would be helpful. Thanks for looking into this for me!

Comment: @Pianoc what you want to test - that AngularJS directives works? This is already tested by Angular team. There is no logic in your code - there is nothing to unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing any attempt at implementing the spec(s) or a stack trace of a failed attempt, I would refer to the following articles/resources to get you started on unit testing directives:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing
- http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/06/introduction-to-unit-test-directives/
- http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-directives.html
- https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing
- http://www.sitepoint.com/angular-testing-tips-testing-directives/
- http://blog.revolunet.com/blog/2013/12/05/unit-testing-angularjs-directive/
- https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-unit-testing-a-directive

---

The rough basics:

- Inject your module to the spec suite.
- $compile the directive template.
- Store the $compiled directive as a variable, available to all of your individual specs.
- Trigger an `.isolateScope().$digest`.
- Write expectations.